# (OCaml: non-exhaustive pattern matching

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I have an OCaml function that returns the value of a specified cell in a table.  The function works correctly but I still get a warning stating:

Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
 Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
 ([],_)

even though I have in fact accounted for that value in my implementation here:

```
let cell_value([i;j],table) = match ([i;j],table) with
      ([],_)      -> []
    | (_,[])      -> []
    | (_::_,_::_) -> List.nth (List.nth table (j-1)) (i-1);;
```

Like I said, the function returns the correct value, I'm just trying to get rid of the error.  I'm still fairly new to OCaml, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your signature is weird. It is much more common to use a tuple in this kind of application than a list. The following would make more sense and would be a lot simpler too : ````let cell_value((i,j),table) = ...````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to what you might believe, the problem is not coming from the pattern-matching introduced by the `match` keyword but by another one you may not be aware of. Indeed, there is a pattern matching in the following fragment of your definition:

```
let cell_value ([i;j], table) = ...
```

because `([i; j], table)` actually contains the pattern `[i; j]`. For this reason, this definition assumes that the first component of the pair given as argument to `cell_value` is a list containing exactly two elements. In other words, this definition is equivalent to:

```
let cell_value = function ([i; j], table) -> ...
```

or also to:

```
let cell_value x = match x with ([i; j], table) -> ...
```

Now, you probably understand the warning issued by the compiler: if you provide a value of the form `([], table)` to your function, it will fail. The compiler is right:

```
# cell_value ([], []);;
Exception: Match_failure ("//toplevel//", 1, 14).
```

Comment: I see.  The warning does make more sense now.  However I'm still unsure of what I need to do to clean it up.  I am not able to change the function prototype, so I must use 'cell_value ([i;j], table'.  Any further tips?  Thank you very much!

Comment: If you need a function that takes two integers, why don't you use a pair instead of a list?

Comment: I admit this is probably not the way I would do it myself, but this is for an assignment so I will lose points if I change the function.  Thank you for your help.